# Open a text file from python script in windows

Tags: python, windows, cmd, terminal, text-editor

I am creating a GUI in Python that needs to be ran in Unix and Windows. In the python main script I need to create and open (like a popup) a text file. I have the code for unix operative system and it is:

```
os.chdir(path=app.sourceFolder+"/Fastq_downloaded")
files = os.listdir(os.getcwd())
sample_data = open("sample_data.txt", "w")
sample_data.write("ID" + "\t" + "Condition" + "\n")
for i in range(len(files)-1):
    sample_data.write(files[i][:-6] + "\t" + "\n")
sample_data.write(files[-1][:-6] + "\t")
sample_data.close()

if "Linux" in o_sys or "Darwin" in o_sys:
    os.system('gedit sample_data.txt')
```

First I create a file with information and then I open it calling the gedit from the terminal. But in windows I don't have any idea of how we can open a text file from terminal and show it to the user. Some advise? Thank you very much

Comment: `notepad sample_data.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

This is simple. In windows you use notepad.

Code:

```
import sys
import os

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    os.system('notepad sample_data.txt')
```

OR to add to your code

```
if "Linux" in o_sys or "Darwin" in o_sys:
    os.system('gedit sample_data.txt')

elif 'win32' in o_sys:
    os.system('notepad sample_data.txt')
```

Comment: I don't think you can find `gedit` for MacOS. (It's probably not installed on Linux either if you are not running Gnome.)

Comment: TextEdit comes bundled with OSX